Looking for an example config for libswan connecting to Cisco ASA with ikev2
I can’t find example of how to set this up. This is my current configuration. I am getting NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN


config setup
  protostack=netkey

conn Tunnel1
  authby=secret
  auto=start
  left=%defaultroute
  leftid=
  leftsourceip=
  right=
  rightid=
  type=tunnel
  ike=aes256-sha256;dh19
  ikelifetime=86400s
  salifetime=28800s
  keyingtries=%forever
  esp=aes256-sha256;dh19
  keyexchange=ike
  leftsubnet=
  rightsubnet=
  dpddelay=10
  dpdtimeout=30
  dpdaction=restart_by_peer


Site to Site Connection with Amazon Linux2 and Cisco ASA
